# Does the closure of a ``nice'' smooth submanifold define a homology class?

Tags: differential-topology, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth compact, oriented manifold. Let 
$X$ be a submanifold which is of the following type 
$$X := \{ p \in M: \psi(p) =0,  ~~\varphi(p) \neq 0 \}  $$
where 
$$ \psi: M \rightarrow V, \qquad \varphi: M \rightarrow W $$
are smooth sections of some oriented vector bundle $V$ and $W$. 
Moreover, when 
$\varphi(p) \neq 0$, the section $\psi$ is transverse to the 
zero set. In particular $X$ is a smooth oriented manifold of the 
right dimension. My question is the following: Given a 
smooth oriented vector bundle $E \rightarrow M$ such that rank of 
$E$ is same as dimension of $X$, is it always possible to 
find a smooth section $s:M \rightarrow E$, transverse to the zero set, 
such that $s^{-1}(0)$ intersects $X$ transversally and 
it does not intersect $\overline{X}-X$ anywhere, 
where $\overline{X}$ is the closure of $X$ inside $M$?

Secondly, is it necessarily true that the object 
$\overline{X}$ defines a homology class in $H_{*}(M,\mathbb{Z})$?
In particular, I want to say that 
$$ < e(E),  [\overline{X}] > = +-| X \cap s^{-1}(0) |  $$

where $e(E)$ is the Euler class of $E$ and $+-|A|$ indicates 
the signed cardinality of the set $A$.

Note that, if $X$ was simply some smooth submanifold of $M$ 
then this may not have been true, because the closure could 
be a very large set. The point here is that $X$ is given as 
the vanishing  and nonvanishing of some sections, which are defined
on the whole of $M$. If instead $\psi$ was defined only partially 
on $M$ (eg a section with poles), then the statement might not have been 
true.